# When to put "of" after "all"?

Tags: determiners, all-of, premodifiers, all-the, partitives

What’s the difference between *all* and *all of*?  When should one use *of* following *all* to make *all of*, and when should one drop the *of* and just use *all* all by itself?

For example, in this sentence:

> How come I can understand spoken American English better than British English **in all its variants**?

Is an *of* required after the *all*, making it *all **of** its variants* instead?

Dunno why but my instincts tell me that I shouldn’t put the *of* in right there. But I am unaware of source of my instinct.

Comment: I am sorry, I am still learning :)

Comment: Related and probable duplicate(s) in some of these: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/4863 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/4906 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/15183 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/58375 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/80696